# Testing Geometry Polygon Data is Valid Using a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, spatial, geometry

We are using a SQL Server Spatial database with the following table setup:

- `SRID` of `27700`
- `geometry_column` of `ogr_geometry`
- `geometry_type` of `POLYGON`

I am using a SQL Server stored procedure to perform the following test:

```
geometry::STGeomFromText(@poly, @srid).STIsValid();
```

When tested the using the following it correctly returns `true`:

```
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@poly ", 200, 1, 50, "POLYGON((1 1, 3 3, 3 1, 1 1))")
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@srid ", 3, 1, 10, 0)
```

When I run the live data (held in the recordset `rs`) it always returns false even though I suspect about half the polygons should be `true`:

```
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@poly ", 200, 1, 1000000000, rs("ogr_geometry"))
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@srid ", 3, 1, 10, 27700)
```

Am I doing anything that is obviously wrong or could it be the case that although some of the geometry works in our system none of it is strictly valid?

I have prepared a [ZIP file with an example polygon](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZaI2_JoPsqqpzrocdbduuCSrFHcoSVnw) that works and one that does not. Both are being flagged by SQL Server as invalid.

Comment: If you have SQL Server Management Studio, you can use Profiler to check the query sent to SQL Server and ensure it's what you expect it to be.

Comment: Are you able to share an example of the ogr_geometry you are putting through.  I would suspect that you having a projection/srid issue.  I am unfamiliar with the projections around the UK (Isle of Man), but with SQL Server you cannot compare geometries without the same SRID or projection.  You may need to do a reprojection of one before the comparison

Comment: Hi @MickyT sure no problem. I would be very grateful if you could take a look at the polygons from the ogr_geometry fields. I have prepared a ZIP file with an example polygon that works and one that does not. Both are being flagged by SQL Server as invalid. The zip file is at https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZaI2_JoPsqqpzrocdbduuCSrFHcoSVnw

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft yes I have Profiler 2017 installed. I think you are onto something there because the RCP log for each query has thousands of encoding `???` in the results with the occasional recognizable character instead of the polygon that I am trying to pass in from the recordset. Here is a truncated example:  `exec dbo.spTestPolygon '? ?? ?????????????z?????? ????'`. It makes me wonder if I am doing something stupid with the way I am passing the recordset field into the sproc.

Comment: I don't see any problems with the polygons posted.  When I checked them using SELECT Geometry::STGeomFromText(' ... ',27700).STIsValid() they are both valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was being caused because the ogr_geometry coming from the recordset had not been cast to a string.

When I changed the field in the recordset to `ogr_geometry.ToString() AS sGeometry` and used `sGeometry` instead of `ogr_geometry` all worked as expected.

Comment: Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an ETL Script, and your .NET client has the geometry type in something that is **NOT** text. My assumption is that it has in an internal OGR format. Rather than creating your geometry instance from text with `STGeomFromText` in SQL Server, instead create the instance in SQL Server from WKB,

- `STGeomCollFromWKB(SqlBytes, Int32)`

WKB is the binary transfer representation. You can create it from `ogr` using, [`OGRGeometry::exportToWkb`](https://www.gdal.org/classOGRGeometry.html#a9a3ad2f9b55285be500ca6ac5dc75d1d)

Just change those two methods. Export to WKB in OGR. Import from WKB in SQL Server.

```
geometry::STGeomCollFromWKB(@poly, @srid).STIsValid();
```

As an aside, OGR itself can determine whether or not the [polygon is valid,](https://www.gdal.org/classOGRGeometry.html#a7bbb194937466a6127b5436ac2ae99d9) there is no reason to use SQL Server at all for this if you already thave the geometry in OGR.